# Retrieve document '_id' of a GridFS document, by its 'filename'

Tags: python, pymongo, information-retrieval, gridfs

I am currently working on a project in which I must retrieve a document uploaded on a MongoDB database using GridFS and store it in my local directory.

Up to now I have written these lines of code:

```
if not fs.exists({'filename': 'my_file.txt'}):
    CRAWLED_FILE = os.path.join(SAVING_FOLDER, 'new_file.txt')
else:
    file = fs.find_one({'filename': 'my_file.txt'})
    CRAWLED_FILE = os.path.join(SAVING_FOLDER, 'new_file.txt')
    with open(CRAWLED_FILE, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(file.read())
    f.close()
```

I believe that `find_one` doesn't allow me to write in a new file the content of the file previously stored in the database. `f.write(file.read())` writes in the file just created (`new_file.txt`) the directory in which (`new_file.txt`) is stored! So I have a txt completely different from the one I have uploaded in the database and the only line in the txt is: `E:\\my_folder\\sub_folder\\my_file.txt`
It's kind of weird, I don't even know why it is happening.

I thought it could work if I use the `fs.get(ObjectId(ID))` method, which, according to the official documentation of Pymongo and GridFS, it provides a file-like interface for reading. However I just know the name of the txt saved in the database, I have no clue what is the object ID, I cannot use a list or dict to store all the IDs of my documents since it wouldn't be worthy. I have checked with many posts here on StackOverflow and everyone suggests to use subscription. Basically you create a cursor using `fs.find()`then you can iterate over the cursor for example like this:

```
for x in fs.find({'filename': 'my_file.txt'}):
    ID = x['_id']
```

see, many answers here suggest me to do the following, the only problem is that Cursor object is not subscriptable and I have no clue how I can resolve this issue.

I must find way to get the document '_id' given the filename of the document so I can later use it combined with `fs.get(ObjectId(ID))`.

Hope you can help me, thank you a lot!
Matteo

Answer (score 2):

You can just access it like this:

```
ID = x._id
```

But "_" is a protected member in Python, so I was looking around for other solutions (could not find much). For getting just the ID, you could do:

```
for ID in fs.find({'filename': 'my_file.txt'}).distinct('_id'):
    # do something with ID
```

Since that only gets the IDs, you would probably need to do:

```
query = fs.find({'filename': 'my_file.txt'}).limit(1) # equivalent to find_one
content = next(query, None) # Iterate GridOutCursor, should have either one element or None
if content:
    ID = content._id
    ...
```